# How to Split an activity to many classes?

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have main activity to for BLE and I have another class for classic Bluetooth. 
I don't know how I can run both at the same time and make them connected. 
Please advise me.

if you can give me some links or something

Update: My app is used as a medium between two devices to support BLE

- The sender device is bluetooth LE
- The Receiver is Classic bluetooth

So I need to write a code which can take the data from sender and push it to the receiver. Thats it

I am using nexus 7 (medium) , glasses(receiver), and micro controller (sender)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: This is not related to my question

Answer (score 0):

Add as a prameter to the constructor of the *classic Bluetooth class* an **Activity** object, and assign it to a veriable.  When creating an object of the *classic Bluetooth class* from the **Activity** just pass the reference to the current Object (the **Activity**). this way anytime you want to access the **Activity** components from the classic Bluetooth class just use the Activity reference.

For example:

```
public class Bluetooth {
    private Activity activity;
    ...

    public Bluetooth(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }
}
```

In the Activity class:

```
Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth(this);
```

Comment: what does the classic bluetooth structure code should look like ? is it the same as main activity....as Oncreate and such ?

Comment: The Bluetooth class should not be an Activity class, since you want to use an object of this class while you are in the MainActivity, and not to create a new Activity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im new here and I will accept it. Can I can explain to you the aim of my app and maybe you would understand me better?

Comment: Yes, please edit the question and add information about what you want to achieve, and what exactly is the structure of your app. Also add code samples within the context of the question.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

You normally do something like this in your activity:

```
MyBLuetoothClass mbc = new MyBluetoothClass();
mbc.doStuff();
```

But it would be helpful if you could provide some code.

Your util class where you want to call methods on can look like this:

```
public class MyFancyUtil {
    // This is your constructor
    public MyFancyUtil(){
    }

    public boolean yourFancyMethod(){
        // Do whatever you want.
    }
}
```

In the Activity you just instantiate and use it like:

```
// Instantiate
MyFancyUtil util = new MyFancyUtil();
// call some method
util.myFancyMethod();
```

Comment: thanks. my code is simple bluetooth pairing connecting. But how should the other class structure look like....same as main activity ?

Comment: Activities are seperate "windows" that are mostly shown one at a time. You probably have a main activity where you show your stuff on. As I understood, your "other class" is just a util class or something. So it just needs a constructor and methods you call.